# How can I automatically create folder under a content item?

Tags: templates, sitecore

Looking at a scenario in which a content editor would create a new content item based off of a template. In other words if I create a content item based off of a car template, I would like to add a folder called 'Options' under the new car item.

As a content editor I could then add various options from the insert command on the folder.

Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a textbook description of a Sitecore Branch Template which can contain anything from a single item to a complex hierarchy of sub-items with their own set of standard-values and insert options. See chapter 3 of the [Data Definition Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf) for how to set these up.

Comment: That looks to be it. Completely neglected looking at that. Thanks!